# How to get keys of dict A after performing set operation set(A.values()) - set(B.values()) cause their all keys are different but few values are same

Tags: python

```
A = {1:('a','b','c','d'), 2:('a','b','d','d'),3:('a','b','c','c')}

B = {111:('a','b','c','d'), 31:('a','b','d','d'),39:('a','b','c','e')}

#After performing.      
data = set(B.values()) - set(A.values())
#i am getting data = ('a','b','c','e')
#But my desired output is 
39 : ('a','b','c','e')'
```

I can't use B.items() as the keys are
different. I can use nested for loops
but I have around 700k+ data and
using that approach is taking a lot
Of
time.  Actually I'm syncing two mssql
Tables using python which has 700k+
data and each row has 52+ values,
earlier
we used to truncate the table B and insert all data from
table A, but it was taking long time.
What we came up with is we did A-B
and then B-A, then inserting all the
A-B rows and deleting all B-A rows.
But
a query with 52 parameters taking
long time in deletion, so I came up
with this idea to delete all the
values
with specific keys, but I'm unable to
get the keys.

Comment: could you invert keys and values?  if so , the result will get you a value that makes to the id u r looking for

Answer (score 1):

You rather need a dictionary comprehension:

```
S = set(A.values())
out = {k:v for k,v in B.items() if v not in S}
```

Output:

```
{39: ('a', 'b', 'c', 'e')}
```

Comment: Looks good, but taking a lot of time.

Comment: @UDIT, try to invert one of dictionaries *(those you want to save keys)* before searching difference, like this `res = set(C := dict(map(reversed, B.items()))).difference(A.values())`. Then you can generate dictionary back using any method you like, e.g. dict comprehension: `{C[i]: i for i in res}`

Comment: @UDIT how much time? What is the exact size of A and B and the number of common values?

Comment: Inversion worked pretty well,

Comment: @mozway A and B are around 700k and common values differ for few tables they are 100k, and for few 250k.